# Eureka - status and info URL do not respect ${management.context-path}

Tags: spring-cloud

The default Eureka instance configuration doesn't take the ${management.context-path} Spring Boot property into account when registering the instance with the Eureka Server.

See `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaInstanceConfigBean`, corresponding properties should probably have the `@Value` annotation on them.

A workaround is to set the path explicitly as follows:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    statusPageUrlPath:  ${management.context-path}/info
    healthCheckUrlPath: ${management.context-path}/health
```

Comment: The integration takes several Spring Cloud default parameters into account like:
eureka.instance.appname = ${spring.application.name}, 
eureka.instance.nonsecureport = ${server.port},
eureka.instance.virtualHostName = ${spring.application.name}.

However, values for the status and health pages are hardcoded to the Spring default values instead of making reference to the corresponding properties.

Documentation is very light and it took me some time to discover the issue. The original intent of my post was to share that knowledge - but nice if you could consider it as a feature request ;-)

Comment: Here's a feature request: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/192